# Entity Framework Core + Npgsql: Query with Include selects depended objects several times

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have encountered in a strange behavior of Npgsql for Entity Framework 7 (EntityFramework7.Npgsql, 3.1.0-rc1-3).

My models:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual List<MySubObject> MySubObjects { get; set; }
}

public class MySubObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual MyObject MyParentObject { get; set; }
    public int MyParentObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

`ApplicationDbContext`:

```
builder.Entity<MyObject>().HasMany(o => o.MySubObjects)
    .WithOne(so => so.MyParentObject)
    .HasForeignKey(so => so.MyParentObjectId)
    .OnDelete(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I have controller action method in which I call private method several times during request processing.

```
public IActionResult GetObjects()
{
    //call GetObject with different parameters
}
```

In GetObject I have something like this:

```
private object GetObject(int id)
{
    return _context.MyObjects.Include(o=>o.MySubObjects).FirstOrDefault(o=>o.Id==id);
}
```

Here the strange thing happens. For example, if `GetObject` gets called three times, then in the first iteration everything's fine, in the second one the actual count of `MySubObject` doubles, int the third one it triples etc. The `MyObject.MySubObjects` contains pairs (thees, fours..) of the same `MySubObject` instances.

Comment: EF7 (now EF Core) has moved quite a lot since RC1, I'm working (on and off) on making the Npgsql EF Core provider available. It would be a good idea to wait for that release and retest before diving too much into this.

Comment: @ShayRojansky Thank you for your answer! I'm looking forward for that